# Calling non-static method directly

Tags: c++, methods, static, call

I am working on a project and I am facing a little bit strange code which I cannot understand why and how can this happen !

I have a class Foo and Baz, and Foo has a non-static method that is called from Baz class without instantiating Foo:

```
class Foo {
    public:
       void qux(int a, int b);
};


class Baz {
    public:
        void bar(void);
};


void Baz::bar(void){
    Foo::qux(2,3);          // This should not happen as qux is not a static method !!
}
```

Comment: are you sure that is the actual code? maybe baz inherits from foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that would work is if `Baz` was derived from `Foo` at some level.

Or, of course, `Foo` bears a different meaning in that scope (via a using, typedef, define or other).

If neither apply, your compiler is seriously broken.

Comment: Exactly, Baz inherits Foo .. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen  in case of `Baz` is inherited from `Foo`.

In this case  you can call method of the base class directly in the form that you mentioned:

```
void Baz::bar(void){
    Foo::qux(2,3);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, Baz inherits Foo .. Thanks for the tip :)